# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net

I just downloaded and installed both the Core 2.2 SDK and the Core 2.2 Runtime. I also updated my version of Visual Studio 17 to the latest version.

To test 2.2, I created a simple ASP.NET Core website and, without changing anything, when I run the application I get the 502.5 error. The same thing happened on a similar setup on my notebook.

I would think that out-of-the box, this should work so I'm thinking something else is going on here. If I create a Core 2.1 application it is fine.

Any suggestions? The given link on the error page seems to cover this generically.

Comment: You should run a report and paste the contents as part of this question, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Common causes of startup issues like **502.5 (Process Failure)** is listed below:

```
1. The application process start application process failed to start. 
2. Started but then stopped. 
3. The application started but failed to listen on the configured port.
```

Things you can try :

1)  **Add CaptureStartupError() and UserSetting() in their Main/program.cs** file as 
     suggested here 
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#startup-exception-handling

2)  Review eventlog.xml for error or exceptions.

3)  **Enable stdoutLogFile**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module#log-creation-and-redirection

4)  When **Detailed Errors** is set to true and **Capture Startup Errors** is true, a **detailed error page is displayed in response to every request** to the server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling#startup-exception-handling

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Close any running apps.
Change default port to something else.
Run VS as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and I'm still getting the same error on a brand new application created using the built-in template. I've decided that 2.2 is not yet ready for prime-time so in the app that I'm building I chose 2.1.